# Align text to image in auto-width container that stretches to image width

Tags: html, css

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qyLjxwrv/1/.

As you can see left and right titles are aligned to screen corners, while I would like to align them to image corners. Trying it for 2hours without a success...

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(213,213,213,.5);
    text-align: center;
}
.info {
    text-align: left;
}
.right-title {
    float: right;   
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="info">
          <span class="left-title">Left</span>
          <span class="right-title">Right</span>
      </div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CRcoPPS.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I don't want titles to appear inside image, but above it and aligned with left and right corner of image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can do it like this simply, and see the comments inline.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Lpu550/)**

```css
.wrapper {
    display: table; /*shrink-to-fit*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*center*/
}
.wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%; /*responsive*/
}
.left-title {
    float: left; /*left*/
}
.right-title {
    float: right; /*right*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
      <div class="info">
          <span class="left-title">Left</span>
          <span class="right-title">Right</span>
      </div>
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/CRcoPPS.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Demos with the gray background color **[partly](http://jsfiddle.net/9z9bqkbk/)** and **[full page](http://jsfiddle.net/zs0p52fL/)**.